# mysqli_stmt_num_rows with prepared statement doesn't return number of rows

Tags: php, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

Prepared statement returns 0 rows when it should return a row:

**My code:**

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test1");
  $myUser = "qqq";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  $sql = 'SELECT `userMail` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`=? LIMIT 1';
  mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $myUser);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $myresult = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
  die(nl2br("myUser = ".$myUser."\nmyresult = ".$myresult));
```

**My data:**
[image]

**The output:**
[image]

---

Where am I wrong...?
$myresult should be 1, for there **IS** such a row...

Comment: mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt) after executing

Comment: @user11222393 - Thank you.   I feel sheepish... It was in front of my eyes and I spent hours trying to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already correctly noticed you need `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` after `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`.
As per PHP docs:

> If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.

However, I need to point out that you don't need it, or in fact you do not need to use [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) at all. I don't think I ever had to use this function myself neither.

What you are trying to achieve is to check if a particular row exists in DB. This can be done as mentioned here: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test1");

$myUser = "qqq";

$sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `userName`=? LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $myUser);
$stmt->execute();
$exists = (bool) $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();

die(nl2br("myUser = ".$myUser."\nmyresult = ".$exists));
```

Of course instead of `(bool) $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()` you could use `(bool) $stmt->get_result()->num_rows`.